# How execute javascript on Openwrt/LEDE firmware

Tags: javascript, openwrt, init.d

I would like a script that can help me to:

- open a website
- submit password

  ```
  javascript:document.getElementById("password").value = "password";auth();
  ```
- when it log in execute other javascript function

  ```
  javascript: function();
  ```

Actually I can do that through computer's browser (as chrome/firefox).

Is there a way to do it through openwrt/LEDE?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Wouldn't it be easier to create a bash script or something? I'm pretty sure you can do everything using ssh that you can in web interface (some lede builds for devices with low amount of flash don't even have it installed by default).

Comment: Yes, if it is possible, i can do that with bash! But how? I only need to autosubmit password in an internal LAN page and after launch a function (simply click on an icon) in the page. But i don't know how to do with bash command...I searched more and more but i only solve with javascript: as i wrote before! I have a lot of space in internal flash!